# Нужно ли ставить тире: «В первой – рассказывается о жизни»?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Для понимания точки зрения автора текст можно разделить на две части.
> В первой – рассказывается о жизни...

Нужно ли тире после «первой»?

Comment: Закончите фразу! Не нужно ли приберечь тире вместо ещё одного **рассказывается**?

Answer (score 1):

> Для понимания точки зрения автора текст можно разделить на две части.
> В первой рассказывается о жизни, во второй - о посмертных мытарствах и
> буднях в аду!

Я так бы написал.

Comment: И правильно сделали бы.

Comment: Мне тоже нравится ответ — по крайней мере, написано грамотно, не без юмора.

Comment: Вот только хорошо было бы добавить в ответ ***Почему*** вы бы так написали (по какому правилу например)